# How to open, save and close Excell Macro-Enabled Worksheet file with Java?

Tags: java, excel, save, auto-update

**Reason**:

To update every single formula result in an existing Excell File.

**Why**:

To be able to extract most up-to-date information from Excell File as otherwise the program displays only result that was manually saved last time when Excell File was open.

**Aim**:

Please could somebody make an example of how to perform this action: 
`Open` -> `Save` -> `Close` 
Lets call this Excell File: **Test.xlsm**

**Solution**:

At the end I found a surprising solution for my problem. Probably better than Apache as my xlsm file had many **user defined formulas** which caused any attempts to evaluate formulas with Apache to throw errors & crashes.

I created a VBS script written inside .vbs file.

```
Set x_Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set x_Open_application = x_application.Workbooks.Open("C:\User\Documents\Project\Test.xlsm")
x_application.Calculate
x_Open_application.Save
x_Open_application.Close False
```

This script would be opened/executed anytime before I start to extract information from my xlsm file. This ensures that results of all formulas in xlsm are **up-to-date**.

My java functions would Open/run VBS Script file before extracting information:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("./" + VBS_File_Name + ".vbs")); //Run VBS File
```

**Benefits of this method:**

*Excel file formulas updated/refreshed through this method won't be visible to the user - work is done in the background.

*Works 100% without Apache.

*Easy to implement.

Comment: You could use the [Apache POI project](https://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: I am so sorry but could you please show me a code that would perform that action from Apache for xlsm file. I literally can't figure it out... more than 6 hours of staying on one point without understanding of what am I doing wrong. Please could you help me. A code that will simply Open Test.xlsm, then refresh formula results/values - save and close Test.xlsm file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic demo of reading a Excel file with POI. The argument is the Excel file name.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class PoiDemo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(bufferedInputStream);) {

            final Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (final Row row : sheet) {
                final String col0 = valueAsString(row, 0);
                final String col2 = valueAsString(row, 2);
                System.out.println("Column 0 =" + col0 + " column 2 = " + col2);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Exception processing excel input", e);
        }
    }

    private static String valueAsString(final Row row, final int i) {
        final Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
        final CellType ct = cell.getCellType();
        switch (ct) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            return cell.getBooleanCellValue() ? "1" : "0";
        case NUMERIC:
            return String.format("%.0f", cell.getNumericCellValue());
        case FORMULA:
        case STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
        default:
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```